# Wrongly adding several tables to masterdb

Tags: sql, sql-server

I add some tables in master database wrongly. Now, I try to drop these tables but I'm getting this error:

> Drop failed for Table 'dbo.COUNTRIES'.
> Could not drop object 'dbo.COUNTRIES' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3726)

[image]

How I drop these tables in my master db?

Comment: By using `DROP`... but you're trying the `DROP` a table referenced by a `FOREIGN KEY`; you can't do that. The error is literally telling you the problem. `DROP` the tables that aren't referenced by foreign keys first.

Comment: In order to DROP the table, you'll need to ALTER the table that references COUNTRIES to remove the foreign key.

Comment: or if the referring table is also unwanted, just drop that first (unless there are circular deps...). Anyway, there is no code showing how these tables were made here, so it's off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to drop all your table from the "detail" windows of the object explorer and to re-click on the OK button many times until all the icons of deleted tables disappears

Comment: That's Old School DBA stuff there